# How to use @BeforeTest in separate java file in testng

Tags: java, testng

I am writing automation testing script for a project . Here , I will have many test classes for which I will be using same @BeforeTest Method . I tried by creating a base class (in which I declared before test method ) and extending them in my test classes . But its not working . Is there any other way to have a common beforeTest method in a seperate java file and use it for all my test classes .

Comment: What `@BeforeTest` are you discussing here? Junit has `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` annotations but not `@BeforeTest`. Are you using another testing framework than Junit?

Comment: I am using TestNG ....(Mentioned in title ..Sry for the obscurity)

Comment: Hmm I thought it was a misspelling of "testing", Sorry haven't used testng

Comment: It would be much easier to fix your problem if you show us your code. Please have a read through [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Using a base class for my other classes works for me. You should use @BeforeMethod for your needs since @BeforeTest is used to run any @Test included in the `<test>` tag in a testNG.xml file.

```
public class BaseClass {
  @BeforeMethod
  public void before() {
    System.out.println("Before method");
  }  
}
```

and then

```
public class ATestClass extends BaseClass {
  @Test
  public void testOne() {
    System.out.println("testOne run");
  }
  @Test
  public void testTwo() {
    System.out.println("testTwo run");
  }
}
```

gave me the result

[image]

Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `PowerMockito` or `Mockito` you can achieve by following.

```
public abstract class ParentClass{
    @Before
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("inniinii");
       }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println("hello test");
      }
}
```